# Spring boot2 - Spring session

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I am trying to configure spring session with Spring boot2 based app.

My pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Session properties,

```
spring.session.jdbc.schema=classpath:org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-mysql.sql
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.table-name=SPRING_SESSION
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

Datasource properties,

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# Connection url for the database
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=select 1
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size = 10
```

Error,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionRepositoryUnavailableException: No session repository could be auto-configured, check your configuration (session store type is 'jdbc')
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$AbstractSessionRepositoryValidator.checkSessionRepository(SessionAutoConfiguration.java:314) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Not sure, what am i missing ...

Comment: Don't think a jdbc autoconfiguration is available for reactive web apps (spring-boot-starter-webflux) [boot-features-session](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-session.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure datasource too to be used by spring session.

```
#application.properties
spring.datasource.url= 
spring.datasource.username= 
spring.datasource.password=
```

And add dependency below too:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: spring-session-code and spring-session-jdbc are already there. Still getting the same error even after adding the above dependency.

Comment: @user1578872 Maybe it's related to reactive stuff and you have to use redis sessions

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It is related to reactive. It works when i add spring-boot-starter-web. I should use redis then.